# Kommasetzung in "Schreibe so schön du kannst."

Tags: comma

Muss in folgendem Satz ein Komma gesetzt werden? Falls ja, welche Regel steckt dahinter? Dieses "so schön du kannst" ist ja eine Art verkürzter Nebensatz. Deswegen ist es mir unklar.

> Schreibe so schön du kannst.

Ich habe im Internet die Schreibweise sowohl mit Komma nach "Schreibe" als auch ohne Komma gefunden.

Comment: Das erste Problem ist die grammatische Analyse. Die Rechtschreibung ergäbe sich dann daraus. Aber schon das erstere ist nicht klar.

Answer (score 4):

Der Teilsatz *so schön du kannst* wird als freier Relativsatz gesehen.
Demenstprechend sollte es lauten:

> Schreibe, so schön du kannst.

---

Alternativ (!) könnten wir - neben *als*, was ich nicht häufig höre - auch *wie* verwenden, und den Satz wie folgt bilden:

> Schreibe so schön, wie du kannst.

> Schreibe, so schön wie du kannst.

In jedem Fall muss natürlich ein Komma stehen.

Quelle: Dudenband 4 (2009) Nr.1668

Comment: Die Frage ist doch klar gestellt. Nach **...wie du kannst** wird nicht gefragt. Also was sollen die alternativen Formulierungen?

Comment: @Olafant Wie in der anderen Antwort klar wird, besteht ein Missverständnis. Dementsprechend ist es nützliche Zusatzinformation. Wenn Sie sich über "Post-Bloating" beschweren wollen, gibt es da deutlich passendere Kandidaten auf diesem Stackexchange für, aber sicherlich nicht meine kurzen Antworten. Beispielsweise könnten Sie sich das Posting von Schölnast (hier: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/75714/seltsam-sei-es-indirekte-rede/75715?noredirect=1#comment180081_75715) anschauen und dort Ihre Beschwerde absondern.

Comment: Ich habe eine Frage gestellt und keine Beschwerde abgesondert.  Die Antwort war m.E. vor dem Hinzufügen der alternativen Formulierungen gut und vollständig.

Answer (score -1):

Schreibe so schön, (wie) du kannst.

Comment: Nein. Es sind sowohl "Schreibe so schön, wie du kannst", "Schreibe, so schön du kannst", "Schreibe, so schön wie du kannst" als auch Varianten mit "als" möglich. 
Dass hier eine Auslassung von "wie" vorliegt, ist nicht klar feststellbar, und wenn man es wie du in Klammern setzen würde (also auslassen würde), wäre es sowieso falsch.