# “Seltsam sei es…”: Indirekte Rede?

Tags: subjunctive, indirect-speech, grammatical-mood

Ich bin dabei, den Roman „Die Vermessung der Welt“ zu lesen, und der Dialog geht so:

> Seltsam **sei** es und ungerecht, sagte Gauß, so recht ein Beispiel für die erbärmliche Existenz …

Wieso ist es „sei“?  Alles, was gesagt wird, scheint im Konjunktiv I zu sein. Ist das indirekte Rede?  Aber mir scheinen diese Stellen lauter Zitate zu sein, also wunderte ich mich, ob das vielleicht eine veraltete Weise zu sprechen war. (Dies alles findet im Jahr 1828 statt.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ja, das ist indirekte Rede, aber hier werden keine wörtlichen Zitate realer Personen wiedergegeben.

Hier ist ein etwas längerer Ausschnitt, so wie ihn Kehlmann geschrieben hat:

> Eugen wiegte zweifelnd den Kopf.
> Seltsam sei es und ungerecht, sagte Gauß, so recht ein Beispiel für die erbärmliche Zufälligkeit der Existenz, daß man in einer bestimmten Zeit geboren und ihr verhaftet sei, ob man wolle oder nicht. Es verschaffe einem einen unziemlichen Vorteil vor der Vergangenheit und mache einen zum Clown der Zukunft.
> Eugen nickte schläfrig.
> Sogar ein Verstand wie der seine, sagte Gauß, hätte in frühen Menschheitsaltern oder an den Ufern des Orinoko nichts zu leisten vermocht, wohingegen jeder Dummkopf in zweihundert Jahren sich über ihn lustig machen und absurden Unsinn über seine Person erfinden könne. Er überlegte, nannte Eugen noch einmal einen Versager und widmete sich dem Buch.
> Während er las, starrte Eugen angestrengt aus dem Kutschenfenster, um sein vor Kränkung und Wut verzerrtes Gesicht zu verbergen.

In der folgenden Version wird hingegen alles, was gesprochen wird, in direkter Rede wiedergegeben. (Ich verwende hier weiterhin die alte Rechtschreibung, die auch Kehlmann in seinem Roman benutzt hat, obwohl er 9 Jahre nach der Rechtschreibreform erschienen ist.)

> Eugen wiegte zweifelnd den Kopf.
> Gauß sagte: »Seltsam **ist** es und ungerecht, so recht ein Beispiel für die erbärmliche Zufälligkeit der Existenz, daß man in einer bestimmten Zeit geboren und ihr verhaftet **ist,** ob man **will** oder nicht. Es **verschafft** einem einen unziemlichen Vorteil vor der Vergangenheit und **macht** einen zum Clown der Zukunft.
> Eugen nickte schläfrig.
> Gauß sagte: »Sogar ein Verstand wie der **meine** ***hätte*** in frühen Menschheitsaltern oder an den Ufern des Orinoko nichts zu leisten vermocht, wohingegen jeder Dummkopf in zweihundert Jahren sich über **mich** lustig machen und absurden Unsinn über **meine** Person erfinden **kann**.« Er überlegte, **sagte noch einmal »Versager« zu Eugen** und widmete sich dem Buch.
> Während er las, starrte Eugen angestrengt aus dem Kutschenfenster, um sein vor Kränkung und Wut verzerrtes Gesicht zu verbergen.

Kehlmann verwendet indirekte Rede aus zwei Gründen:

1. Nichts von dem, was Kehlmann seiner Romanfigur Gauß in den Mund legt, hat der echte Carl Friedrich Gauß (1777-1855; deutscher Mathematiker, Statistiker, Astronom, Geodät, Elektrotechniker und Physiker) tatsächlich gesagt. *Die Vermessung der Welt* ist kein Tatsachenbericht, sondern ein Roman mit einer fiktiven Handlung. Einige der Figuren, die in dem Roman vorkommen, haben zwar Namen und wichtige Eigenschaften real existiert habender Menschen, aber die Figuren in dem Buch sind dennoch das Ergebnis von Kehlmanns Fantasie. Bei der indirekten Rede wird etwas aus zweiter Hand wiedergegeben, wodurch der Zuhörer weiß, dass es möglich ist, dass der Text durch den Überbringer bewusst oder unbewusst verfälscht worden sein könnte. Kehlmann nutzt diese Wahrnehmung der indirekten Rede, um dem Leser klarzumachen, dass mit seiner Romanfigur nicht die reale historische Person gemeint ist.
2. Durch die indirekte Rede wird der Text vom Indikativ, der sehr häufig verwendet wird, in den Konjunktiv verschoben, wodurch der Text auf der rein sprachlichen Ebene ungewöhnlich und dadurch kunstvoll und edel erscheint. Das ist die Entsprechung dessen, was in der bildenden Kunst eine Fotographie von einem Gemälde unterscheidet. Kehlmann verwendet auch noch andere Methoden auf der rein sprachlichen Ebene (z.B. modifizierter Satzbau), um den Text zu veredeln, mit dem Zweck aus einer schnöden Erzählung ein literarisch hochstehendes Stück Weltliteratur zu machen. Das Deutsch in Kehlmanns Büchern ist in vielerlei Hinsicht anders als das Deutsch, das Menschen im Alltag oder in Sachbüchern verwenden. Vor allem ist es *nicht* die Sprache, die reale Menschen wie Gauß, Humbold usw. Anfang des 19. Jahrhunderts verwendet haben, sondern es ist eine moderne kunstvolle Sprache, die erst im 21. Jahrhundert von Kehlmann niedergeschrieben wurde. Kehlmanns Deutsch ist Literatur.

Zu beachten ist, dass beim Transformieren von der indirekten Rede in die direkte, nicht jedes Verb, das im Konjunktiv steht, in den Indikativ übertragen wird.

Beispiel:

- Indirekte Rede

  > Sogar ein Verstand wie der seine, sagte Gauß, ***hätte*** in frühen Menschheitsaltern oder an den Ufern des Orinoko nichts zu leisten vermocht, ...
- Direkte Rede

  > Gauß sagte: »Sogar ein Verstand wie der meine ***hätte*** in frühen Menschheitsaltern oder an den Ufern des Orinoko nichts zu leisten vermocht,

Das Wort *»hätte«* steht nicht im Konjunktiv I (der wäre *»habe«*) sondern im Konjunktiv II und wird nicht von Kehlmann verwendet, um die indirekte Rede auszudrücken, sondern er wird von Gauß selbst verwendet, um etwas nicht-reales zu beschrieben (daher hat der Konjunktiv II auch seinen zweiten Namen: *»Irrealis«*). Nicht nur der echte Gauß, sondern auch der Gauß aus Kehlmanns Erzählung hat nicht in frühen Menschheitsaltern gelebt oder war jemals am Orinoko. Der Kehlmannsche Gauß sagt nur, dass er damals und dort etwas nicht gekonnt hätte, wenn er damals gelebt bzw. dort gewesen wäre. Aber er hat in Wahrheit nicht damals gelebt und er war in Wahrheit nicht dort.

---

Der Teil *»wohingegen jeder Dummkopf in zweihundert Jahren sich über ihn lustig machen und absurden Unsinn über seine Person erfinden könne.«* bezieht sich übrigens genau auf die Tatsache, dass Kehlmann sich 200 Jahre nach der Zeit, in der der Roman spielt, über Gauß lustig macht und absurden Unsinn über ihn erfindet. Der echte Gauß konnte das nicht ahnen und wird es daher auch niemals gesagt haben. Damit macht Kehlmann noch einmal klar, dass das, was er Gauß in den Mund legt, nicht vom echten C.F.Gauß stammt, sondern aus Kehlmanns Fantasie.

Comment: *Kehlmann nutzt diese Wahrnehmung der indirekten Rede, um dem Leser klarzumachen, dass mit seiner Romanfigur nicht die reale historische Person gemeint ist.* Braucht der Leser diese Hilfe? Wenn in einem Roman direkte Rede vorkommt, wird der Leser die Romanfiguren doch nicht für real halten?

Comment: @DavidVogt: Du schreibst *»Wenn in einem Roman direkte Rede vorkommt, wird der Leser die Romanfiguren doch nicht für real halten?«* Der Fragesteller war da offensichtlich anderer Meinung. Von mir korrigiertes Zitat aus seiner Frage: *»Aber mir scheinen diese Stellen lauter Zitate zu sein, also wunderte ich mich, ob das vielleicht eine veraltete Weise zu sprechen war.«* Originalversion: *»Aber mir scheinen diese alle Zitate zu sein, also wunderte ich mich, ob es vielleicht eine veraltete Weise zu sprechen wäre«.*

Answer (score 2):

Bei einem Satz wie deinem spricht man von einer **Übergangsform zwischen indirekter und berichteter Rede**.

Solchen Sätzen fehlt der Einleitungssatz bzw. kann der Sprecher eingeschoben sein wie bei dir.

Dudenband 4 (2009) Nr. 1850, 771, **774**

Meiner Ansicht nach ist die Fragestellung hiermit perfekt beantwortet. Es wird sogar die Quelle angegeben.

Comment: ich verstehe die Zweifel nicht, ob es sich um indirekte Rede handeln könnte. Syntaktisch haben wir hier indirekte Rede in Reinform. Man vergleiche die Beispiele auf https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirekte_Rede. Der einzige Unterschied ist, dass der Hauptsatz eingeschoben ist.

Comment: @RHa Der exakt gleiche Satzbau wie in der Fragestellung erscheint unter Nr. 774 im Dudenband 4 (2009) als Zweifelsfall. Es geht lediglich darum, wie selbstständig die Rede ist. Mit "berichtete Rede" ist nicht direkte Rede gemeint.

Comment: Die Antwort ist so knapp gehalten, daß die meisten Leser den Unterschied zwischen indirekter und berichteter Rede nicht verstehen. Hinzu kommt, daß die Duden-Grammatik (wie andere Quellen auch) *sagte Gauß* als parenthetisch wertet, also entgegen der Erwartung der meisten Leser kein abhängiger Verbzweitsatz vorliegt.